# Unable to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView" in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to resolve this annoying bug and I have tried every possible option. I went through the previous SO answers and tried invalidating caches and restart. I also made sure that my support dependency in gradle are correct but for some reason my app crashes when I run it on my phone with the following errors.

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                     at com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample.Camera2BasicFragment.onCreateView(Camera2BasicFragment.java:455)
                                                     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2352)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
                                                     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:815)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
                                                     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6689)
12-12 17:00:55.442 8215-8215/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2687)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
12-12 17:00:58.120 804-903/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".CameraActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me out. I am really confused with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually because you're using the wrong package name for your view. You're trying to include view with:

```
<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ...
/>
```

which probably not the right package name if we compare it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` package name, i.e `com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample">

   ...

</manifest>
```

So, change `com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView` to your View package name where the class `AutoFitTextureView` reside. It maybe something like this:

```
<com.example.surajit.camera2apiexample.AutoFitTextureView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ...
/>
```